# Get data from one entity with data from second entity

Tags: grails, entity, one-to-many

I have 2 entity with relation one-to-many. I need get result from entity with data from relation entity. This is one of variant witch I try

```java
class Question {
    int id
    String question
    List<Answer> answers
    static hasMany = [answers : Answer]
//  static mappedby = [ answers: 'QuestionID' ]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

```java
class Answer {

    int id

    String answer

    boolean isCorrect
    static belongsTo = Question
//  static belongsTo = [ question: Question]
//  Question question

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

After query

```java
class QuestionController {
    def index() { 
        def questionList = Question.findAll() as JSON   
        [questionList: questionList]
    }
}
```

I got a result

> [{"class":"ua.home.testknowledge.Question","id":6,"answers":[],"question":"2+2=?"},...]

But in result I what get answers with data from entity answer

In java it's easy to do but how with grails to do I can't find solution.

I think you understand what I mean.

Thx!

Comment: Two things needs clarification - 1. Why `int id`? If at all then where is the mapping for `id`? 2. Why `static belongsTo = [ question: Question]` is commented and not used for one-many?

Comment: Set grails.converters.json.default.deep to true in your config.

Answer (score 0):

onfiguring Eager Fetching in order to get the answers as part of Json response.

```
class Question {
    int id
    String question
    List<Answer> answers
    static hasMany = [answers : Answer]
    answers lazy: false
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

In this case the answers association will be loaded at the same time as its Question instance, although a second query will be executed to fetch the collection.

And set `grails.converters.json.default.deep to true` in your config as Sergio said above.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. This entity's create own fields in exist tables and if get data from this fields I receive data what I want.